# IIS URL Rewrite Module ignores rule with child app in path

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to do a URL rewrite on a certain path on my site that contains the child app in the path. The issue is that when I have the name of my child app in the path, the rule gets skipped.

So I have the current IIS setup:

```
Root App (example.com)
|
|---Child App (mychild)
```

Let's say the site is `http://example.com`

I can access the child app via `http://example.com/mychild/...`

Now I need to make a URL rewrite rule that will catch a specific URL that's under the child app. So for example *this* would need to be matched:

`http://example.com/mychild/folder1/method1` and rewritten to something else

When I put this rule in (the root site `web.config`) however (regex removed for simplicity), the rule is not triggered, it continues to route to the child app, and results in a 404:

```
<rule name="rule1" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="mychild/folder1/method1" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://otherlocalserver"
</rule>
```

If I change the `mychild` instance in the `url` attribute to something else (that's not a child app), like:

`<match url="hello/folder1/method1" />`

This: `http://example.com/hello/folder1/method1` ***will*** match.

How can I get this rule to apply *before* IIS thinks that I want it to use the `child` application?

Answer (score 0):

Is the child app running as a seperate website?

Then you should do the rewrite path in the correct web.config file.

If not, then there is probably some other rule targeting the path you are trying to target with a stopProcessing="true" tag (like the one in the rule you posted here).